# Using Crystal Report with SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm developing a local application with C#, and I would like to use Crystal Reports but when I use the wizard it doesn't have the SQL Server CE oledb connection, so I was asking if there's a way to do it programatically or any other way? :D